# I Can't call the methods in C# am using

Tags: c#

This is my code

Basic Calculator Using 2 methods
1 is the main method
2 is the operator

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num1;
            int num2;                   //Variables for equation
            string op;
            //int Answer;


            Console.Write("Enter the first number : ");
            num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //User input for equation
            Console.Write("Now enter your second number : ");
            num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Ok now enter your operation ( x , / , +, -) ");
            op = Console.ReadLine();
            Methods1();       // This is the error, The error says
                          // There's no argumen given that corresponds
        }

    

        static int Methods1(int num1, int num2, string op)
        {
            if (op == "+")
            {
                return num1 + num2;
            }
            else if (op == "-")
            {
                return num1 - num2;
            }
            else if (op == "/")
            {
                return num1 / num2;
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                return num1 * num2;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
                return 0;
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've declared your method as `int Methods1(int num1, int num2, string op)` but you call it without parameters `Methods1()`.

Comment: Please advise waht problem you're facing, and include any error messages.

Comment: Methods1(num1, num2,op); please update the error line like this

Comment: @Llama noted!!!

Comment: @VaraPrasad.M thankyouusomuch!

Comment: Next, you should go back and re-read the error message - notice how it tells you *exactly* what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called the `Methods1()` method without arguments. Change the code to the following:

```
using System;

namespace Test_app_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num1;
            int num2;                   //Variables for equation
            string op;
            int Answer;


            Console.Write("Enter the first number : ");
            num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //User input for equation
            Console.Write("Now enter your second number : ");
            num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Ok now enter your operation ( * , / , +, -) ");
            op = Console.ReadLine();
            Answer = Methods1(num1, num2, op);       // Now no error...
            Console.WriteLine(Answer + "\nPress any key to exit...");   //You forgot to add Console.Writeline
            Console.Read();    //Also forgot Console.Read
        }



        static int Methods1(int num1, int num2, string op)
        {
            if (op == "+")
            {
                return num1 + num2;
            }
            else if (op == "-")
            {
                return num1 - num2;
            }
            else if (op == "/")
            {
                return num1 / num2;
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                return num1 * num2;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
                return 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr! It's help me a lot

Comment: Welcome! You can also upvote if helped...

Comment: Okay no worries